# C# record ToString() causes stack overflow and stops debugging session with a strange error

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I wrote a unit test and used the new C# record to store some data I needed for testing. The unit test run fine, but when I set a break point and moved the mouse over the record variable name, the debugging session ended and I got a strange looking error message.

To report the problem to Microsoft, I wrote a simple unit test, which demonstrates the problem, but doesn't make much sense otherwise:

```
#nullable enable
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace CSharpRecordTest {

  record Twin(string Name) {
    public Twin? OtherTwin { get; set; }
  }

  [TestClass]
  public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
      var twinA = new Twin("A");
      var twinB = new Twin("B");
      twinA.OtherTwin = twinB;
      twinB.OtherTwin = twinA;
      Assert.AreEqual(twinA, twinA.OtherTwin.OtherTwin);
    }
  }
}
```

The test runs fine, but when setting a break point at Assert.AreEqual( and moving the mouse over twinA, the debugging session stops and this error message gets shown:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me a day or two to figure out what was happening, because the debugger did not let me see anything. I wrote a console application:

```
class Program {
  record Twin(string Name) {
    public Twin? OtherTwin { get; set; }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var twinA = new Twin("A");
    var twinB = new Twin("B");
    twinA.OtherTwin = twinB;
    twinB.OtherTwin = twinA;
    Console.WriteLine(twinA);
  }
}
```

The console application also run into troubles, but at least it showed that there was a stack overrun and  which line it caused:

```
Console.WriteLine(twinA);
```

The stack looked something like this (although more complicated):

```
twinA.OtherTwin.OtherTwin.OtherTwin.OtherTwin.OtherTwin.OtherTwin...OtherTwin.ToString()
```

The problem is that ToString(), which gets automatically written by the compiler, calls .ToString() again on every property.

If a record references itself or other records which then reference the first record, ToString() will fail and needs to get overriden together with Equals(), GetHashCode() and maybe more (I didn't try it).

Actually, when having a property which is not readonly, Equals() and GetHashCode() should be overriden, otherwise classes like Dictionary will not work.

For more details, see my article on CodeProject: [C# 9 Record: Compiler Created ToString() Code can Lead to Stack Overflow and Worse](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5300961/Csharp-9-Record-Compiler-Created-ToString-Code-can)

Comment: Lets hope a MS employee will see this, otherwise you might wanna report it here https://github.com/dotnet probably runtime repo, not 100% sure.

Comment: I had the same issue with a `Node` record that had a `Node Next` property. It is indeed the way the built-in ToString works for records. At the time I checked the c# repo and it had already been reported but I'm having difficulty finding it since the Google search term "stack overflow" leads back here. The work around was a custom ToString for the type, though be careful if you then inherit from that record type and want to use *its* ToString override  you have to explicitly call `base.ToString`

Comment: Though here's the design meeting notes where they acknowledge this can happen and basically leave it as is: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/3c8559f186d4c5df5d1299b0eaa4e139ae130ab6/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-08-24.md#handling-stack-overflows

Comment: @CSharpie I actually did report it on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/5068. The response was: This is by design. In my view, this is a bad design, for a detailed explanation see my codeproject article.